# ABAP regex which considers dynamic texts

Tags: regex, abap

I have a string which somewhere contains:

```
{"id":"ID_A","name":"Test","visible":false},{"id":"ID_B","name":"Hallo","visible":false},...
```

I want to replace the visible value of ID_A so it becomes:

```
{"id":"ID_A","name":"Test","visible":true},{"id":"ID_B","name":"Hallo","visible":false},...
```

The ID is always the same. I don't want to change the visible parameter of all other objects (e.g. ID_B).

Important: the value of the name property is dynamic. So I need some regex which works for different values of the name property.

Furthermore, I can not expect that the ID_A object is always the first. Maybe the order can change.

Since I'm no regex expert I would be glad if someone could help.

Comment: Isn't that JSON? Why not using a JSON parser?

Comment: It is a string actually. It only contains such JSON parts.

Comment: Even with parts, a JSON parser on these parts is better.

Comment: So how would the JSON parsing be done in ABAP? Do you use /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize in case you are aware of the corresponding ABAP structure? And /ui2/cl_json=>serialize to get JSON again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend a regular expression for JSON parsing, because a RegEx may not work in a number of cases.

In ABAP, something like that might work in most of cases:

```
DATA: text TYPE string, pattern TYPE string.

pattern = '("id":"ID_A"[^}]*"visible":)false'.

text = '{"id":"ID_A","name":"Test","visible":false},'
    && '{"id":"ID_B","name":"Hallo","visible":false},...'.
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX pattern
    IN text WITH '$1true'.
```

The above regular expression wouldn't work if an element value contains `}`, or if there's an extra space somewhere, etc.

Explanations of the regular expression:

- `(...)` means the registering of a subgroup (can be replaced by indicating `$` followed by the number of subgroup, e.g. `$1` in the code above)
- `[^...]` any character that is not in the list of proposed characters, e.g. `[^}].` means any character that is not a `}`
- `*` : kleene star to permit 0 or any number of repetitions of the previous character or group

Answer (score 1):

I've never used ABAP, but the general regex that can help you achieve what you want is like so:

```
((?<="id":"ID_A").*?"visible":)false([,}].*)
```

You then need to substitute while using the capture groups in the regexp.

You can find an example here: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=115947

Just open the "Substitution" section and enter `$1true$2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For ABAP the 'false' must be the match in order to replace it. In your sample it is a little bit different. I tried to have only the 'false' marked/matched but so far it did not work...